# Running script on fedora cloud image at boot

Tags: fedora, scripting, boot, cloud

I need a little help from you on a project i'm working on with the Fedora Cloud image.

Since it's a cloud image, during boot, it sends out HTTP request to locate the meta-data service. After multiple tries, when it fails, the network service stops and we do not see ifconfig eth0 get an IP via DHCP. Eth0 only comes up once we manually do a "systemctl restart network". We were wondering if we could create a custom script on the qcow so that it issues the command "systemctl restart network" right after boot so that it need not be done manually.
I found this article: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cloudinit/latest/cloudinit.pdf where we could add custom scripts to cloud-final.service and tried the same, but was unable to get it to run.

I also saw a post about creating an /etc/rd.d/rc.local file and mentioning the script in there. I was wondering if the script needs to be put under rc.local file of cloud-final.service.

It would be great if you could help us with this

Regards,
Antara

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
create custom image, and edit systemd:

```
systemctl edit cloud-init.service
```

([Reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1621671))